# Chrome Form Input Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

This problem is completely perplexing to me. 
Chrome will not let me edit form fields, or click buttons, inside of Fancybox run from my server. The cursor doesn't even blink. On my laptop the 'X' icon to the top right of the light box is there, but it doesn't show up when I test it on my mom's laptop. I have the newest FancyBox version and am using Jquery 1.9.1. [image: First example] [image: Second example]

However, if I use [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMb4p/3/) for my code then it works.
I discovered that if I resize the browser window then the information shows.

Here's the form's HTML:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form id="question_form" method="post" action="">
        <p>Please enter your correct information so we can help you.</p>
        <p>
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="30">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="30">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="qmessage">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="qmessage"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#question_form_link").fancybox({
        'scrolling': 'no',
        'titleShow': true,
        'onClosed': function () {}
    });
}); //end ready
```

**EDIT Added tabindex property**
This is what you see after pressing tab several times.
[image: Weird thing, but you can actually type]
[image: Looks normal and seems to work after browser window is resized.]

Comment: How does this work? The `id` of the element is "question_form", but you use `$("#question_form_link")`

Comment: @Ian : `#question_form_link` should be the selector bound to fancybox (most likely a link) that targets the selector `#question_form` (most likely via `href`) if you know how fancybox works

Comment: @JFK Ahh yes, that was silly of me. I should've just looked at the jsFiddle. I didn't think the `id` of the target fancybox would be in the `href` :)

Comment: @Drue : you are not the first reporting that as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/16002880/1055987 I haven't had time to dig into the issue but my first thought was adding `tabindex="1"` attribute to the form and/or form fields. I have solved other issues with Chrome and ajax content with that trick. Regarding the close button in your mom's laptop, is because the image hasn't been cached and it depends on where you are pulling the sprite from.

Comment: @JFK Thanks. I'll try it tomorrow. I'm on my ipad right now. Works on this too. I can't figure out why it works on Chrome in JsFiddle, but not under localhost.

Comment: @JFK Sad to say that it doesn't help. I'm posting more pictures.

Comment: @Drue This is a silly question, but have you checked your browsers's console to see if any errors/warnings occur? Although this code seems simple, something weird may be happening on a full web page instead of a fiddle

Comment: @Drue : pictures don't help either, can you share the link to the page with the issue?

Comment: @JFK Yes. Later on today most likely. Sorry for not being on a a couple weeks. I've been really busy. Weird thing, it works fine on my school's computer using Chrome. Chrome for XP.

Comment: @JFK http://www.gracepensacola.com/test/contact_us.php

Comment: It's the link in the bottom right blue box.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m (Windows) .... I can focus on any field and press `submit` with no issue. BTW, your fancybox custom script has options for v1.3.4 that are not compatible with v2.1.4, the version you are using.

Comment: @JFK This is getting on my nerves! I have the exact same version and it won't allow me. It won't allow me to do this on my mom's laptop either on Chrome. I've force reloaded the page, uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome. Should I just ignore the problem? Also, I'll fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Still having problems so I switched Light boxes in my testing suite.